# Can't run 1 simple test remotely using a test controller and agent.

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

I'm about to start pulling hair out, 3 days of trying to get even 1 simple test to run, and nothing!

Here is what I've got so far.

I have a visual studio 2013 solution with a project that contains the test. The solution has a Default.testsettings file -> here under roles you can configure the controller.

Now we actually have a fancy setup with separate controller and agent machines - I've given up on all of that for now.

Instead I have one vm which is now hosting both the controller and the agent. Also to simplify everything, the controller is not registered with TFS team project collection.

This is what is happening:

Firstly in Visual Studio on my local dev pc, I am able to add the controller via the testsetting file - and it actually connects!

Another bit of success is that I can get the agent to an online status, so it's registered to the controller and connected.

The problem comes when I try and run the test, it takes forever and then the test is skipped. Instead this error message is produced:

Firstly when I try and disconnect the agent (I did this just to prove the visual studio client seems to be able to at least connect to the controller)

Failed to queue test run '[mydetails] 2014-10-24 23:44:13': Test run '[mydetails] 2014-10-24 23:44:13' could not be executed on controller [controllerMachineName]. No agents are marked online to execute test run.

Then when the agent is connected:

Failed to queue test run 'MLeppan@ATSCZNB047 2014-10-24 23:53:02': A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

I just have no idea how to progress on this, it should just work.

At this stage, any hints, answers or the solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is not clear what you try to accomplish. A Test Controller is managed from VS or from TFS but not both. Distributed architectures work perfectly when firewalls are properly configured.

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. Connect your test controller to TFS
2. Create a Test Case and associate it to your test
3. Create a build that builds both your app and the test Assemblies
4. Create a Standard Environment in MTM
5. Execute the test from MTM targeting a specific build and environment

http://nakedalm.com/standard-environments-for-automated-deployment-and-testing/

I usually go one further and automate the deployment part as well: http://nakedalm.com/execute-tests-release-management-visual-studio-2013/

Once you have an environment however, with a version of your app installed your test infrastructure should work as you expect.